# How do I tie an image stored in Firebase Storage to a record in Firebase Database? *SWIFT/iOS*

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

Hello I am trying to associate an image stored in Firebase storage to a record in Firebase Database.  The records in the database are stored using `childByAutoID()`.

I would like to be able to store an image using the same auto generated ID, but can't figure out how to retrieve that ID.  Thanks.

Comment: Check out Zero to App: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xAsvwy1-oxE and it's associated code: https://gist.github.com/mcdonamp/cc45567cd95ba2a62017cb21e891effd which show how you can do this.

Comment: Thanks Mike, this is what I was looking for!